# How to bind combination of db fields to single property (C#, WinForms, LINQ to SQL)?

Tags: winforms, linq-to-sql, data-binding

I want to bind single control attribute (TextBox.Text) to combination of database fields using Linq to SQL (in C#/WinForms project).

For example:

1) I have a table Customer with columns CustomerName, CustomerCity and IsBigCustomer (boolean)

2) On a WinForm I have a TextBox "cInfo" and a ListBox "cList"

3) I have binded "cList" to CustomerName column (when I change item in cList, I need the appropriate Customer data presented in cInfo.Text)

4) I want to bind "cInfo" TextBox.Text property to combination of database columns - for example i would like to show:

a) "!"+CustomerName+": "+CustomerCity (if Customer's IsBigCustomer=true)

b) CustomerName+": "+CustomerCity (if Customer's IsBigClient=false)

And when a user changes cInfo.Text I need it to be validated and changes sent back to database (if validation is successful)

```
Sample data:
{IBM, New York, true} => cInfo.Text should be "!IBM: New York"
(SmallCustomer, Paris, false) => cInfo.Text should be "SmallCustomer: Paris"
```

How can I accomplish this task?

(The question is not about usefulness of such an aproach, but to understand if it is possible to bind more than one db field to one property and how to do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the validation of the data.  If you have it in a text field they can put anything, how about if someone puts in "Some!Big:Company:Bad:!Data"  What would that do for you...

I can only suggest that on your form, you have something like..

```
Checkbox for "Big Client"
Textbox for the Name
Textbox for the City
```

then, pushing the data back to the server is much easier too.

Comment: OK, but is it possible to create such a "combined" binding? I want to make an easy way to enter/change data (given example is not very illustrative though)

Comment: OK, but is it possible to create such a "combined" binding? I want to make a very easy way to enter/change data not moving through 3 controls (sorry, given example is not very helping to explain why it would be worth making such a binding)

Comment: OK, I suppose this is not possible in winforms :( Although this answer is not giving what I need, i suppose it directs in the only possible direction, so I will mark it as answer. Thanks!